How do I extract a house number and addition from an address?
I have to write a computer program that splits a house number, and also recognizes the house number addition, from an address line.
This only concerns Dutch addresses.
Example testcases are:

"Notenkrakerstraat 24" (house number=24, no additions)
"Stationsstraat 7a" (house number=7, addition="a")
"Molenweg 3 hs" (house number=3, addition="hs")
"18 Septemberplein 12" (house number=12, no additions)
"Kerkstraat 2-2" (house number=2, addition="-2")
"Hoofdstraat 2 - 2" (house number=2, addition="- 2")
"Plein 1944 1a 1e etage" (house number=1, addition="a 1e etage")
"Plein 1944 1 a 1e etage" (note the space between the '1' and the 'a')

I'm interested in a good idea regarding the approach. It doesn't have to be a detailed program.
If you still want to get your teeth into it... it should eventually become a cobol routine !

Logically speaking why is the house number not 1944 in the last two cases?

No logic but Plein 1944 is the street name (or square name in this case) where 1944 is the year for which we remember something. There's probably no real solution to this question however because these things can not be captured into logic unless you have a database of all street names to compare to.

True: Plein 1944 is the street name (or square name in this case)

Obligatory: Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses
